# is it possible to add line numbers to input files read using \verbatiminput?

Tags: listings, verbatim, latex2html

I know one can use `\usepackage{listings}` which supports line numbers. And I use that for pdf  files. But I also generate HTML using `Latex2html`, and `l2h` does not support this package. It only supports `\verbatiminput`.

Therefore in my latex file (which generates both pdf and html from the same source), I have the following

```
\documentclass[]{book}%
\usepackage{html}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{htmlonly}
   \providecommand{\lstinputlisting}[2][]{\verbatiminput{#2}}
\end{htmlonly}
\lstset{numbers=left}
\begin{document}
  \lstinputlisting{source.txt}
\end{document}
```

So when I type `pdflatex foo.tex` I get line numbers, but when I type `latex2html foo.tex` I only get the source, but no line numbers there.

I have to use latex2html on this file. I know `tex4ht` supports this package, but for other reasons, I need to use `l2h` here.

Is there a trick to do this inside Latex? I know I can generate the source.txt with line numbers externally, and then include that file again using `\verbatiminput` but wanted to see first if possible to do inside Latex using `\verbatiminput` directly.

references:

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatim

[http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2005-March/003659.htm](http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2005-March/003659.html)l

Fyi,

In the above post by Dr Moore he refers to the file `verbatimfiles.perl` in the `l2h` distribution to edit to add this support for line numbers in l2h.

I do not know any Perl (l2h is written in Perl) and do not know how to start to change this file to do this. It is a small file. I'll paste here in the hope someone here who might know Perl can spot as easy one line change to to add a line number to the left. Here is the file `/usr/share/latex2html/styles/verbatimfiles.perl`

```
# $Id: verbatimfiles.perl,v 1.6 1999/04/09 18:16:51 JCL Exp $
# verbatimfiles.perl
#   Jens Lippmann <lippmann@rbg.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de> 6-FEB-96
#
# Extension to LaTeX2HTML to support verbatim.sty/verbatimfiles.sty.

package main;

&do_require_package("verbatim");

sub do_cmd_verbatimfile {
    &do_cmd_verbatiminput;
}

sub do_cmd_verbatimlisting {
    local($_,$outer);
    local($counter) = 0;

    # Read in file, get markup ready.
    $outer = &do_cmd_verbatiminput;

    # Postprocess verbatim content.
    $_ = $verbatim{$global{'verbatim_counter'}};

    #insert numbers for every line
    #but not the first line if it's empty (LaTeX'ism?)
    local($firstemptyline);
    $firstemptyline = $1 if s/^([ \t]+\n)//;

    #and not the last end of line
    s/\n$//;
    s/(^|\n)/$1.sprintf("%4d ",++$counter)/ge;

    #add the stuff from the first(if empty) and last line also
    $verbatim{$global{'verbatim_counter'}} = $first.$_;
    $outer;
}

&process_commands_wrap_deferred (<<_RAW_ARG_DEFERRED_CMDS_);
verbatimfile # {}
verbatimlisting # {}
_RAW_ARG_DEFERRED_CMDS_

1;              # Must be last line
```

btw, I tried to use `do_cmd_verbatimlisting` mentioned above in Latex like this:

```
\verbatimlisting{source.txt}
```

but nothing happened. l2h did not understand the command. So I am not sure if the support for line numbers is there in l2h based on the above source code, but need to figure how to use it or not.

Comment: The executables in the`tex4ht` bundle support the `listings` package with line numbers

Comment: @cmhughes, thank you. Yes I know and I mentioned this in my post. I like Tex4ht also. I am actually changing all my makefiles to use either Latex2html or Tex4ht for the build. This way, I can choose either one to generate HTML and compare the output until I decide which to pick. l2h is a little more flexible when it come to breaking pages and making toc for each page and such, but tex4ht seems to support more packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `verbatimbox` package has the provisions to add preconditioning commands (e.g., line numbers, etc.) to a file listing.  But because it puts it into a box, it is restricted to one page.  That is the first thing I show below (`\verbfilebox` places the file contents in a box, `\theverbbox` regurgitates it).

Then, I took the command from that package and by hand modified it (naming it `\verbfilelist`) to give a verbatim listing across page boundaries (shown in image below), while preserving the ability to give line numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\verbfilebox[\arabic{VerbboxLineNo}:\hspace{1ex}]{junk.tex}
\theverbbox
%    
\makeatletter
\newcommand\verbfilelist[2][]{%
  \setcounter{VerbboxLineNo}{0}%
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
    {\addtocounter{VerbboxLineNo}{1}%
    #1\setbox0=\hbox{#1\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\par}}%
  \verbatiminput{#2}
  \let\verbatim@processline\sv@verbatim@processline
}
\makeatother

\verbfilelist[\arabic{VerbboxLineNo}:\hspace{1ex}]{junk.tex}
\end{document}

This
is
extra
text
to
force
a
page
break
in
the
listing
```

[image]